# Can't run python program from xampp command line

Tags: python, xampp

I write a code in python to scrape some data from a web site using selenium. this code completely work when i run it in system command line . But when i run it from xampp command line it give error and show this message

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\Marajul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py",
>   line 72, in start
>       self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,   File "C:\Users\Marajul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py",
>   line 854, in **init**
>       self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,   File
>   "C:\Users\Marajul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py",
>   line 1307, in _execute_child
>       hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args, FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file
>   specified
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\xampp\htdocs\Dairy\API\toph\python\a.py", line 16, in 
>       driver = Chrome(webdriver)   File "C:\Users\Marajul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py",
>   line 73, in **init**
>       self.service.start()   File "C:\Users\Marajul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py",
>   line 81, in start
>       raise WebDriverException( selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message:
>   'chromedriver3.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see
>   https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
import pandas as pd
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="root",
  passwd="",
  database="dairy"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

webdriver = 'chromedriver3.exe'

driver = Chrome(webdriver)
cnt=0

while 1:
    page_nb=(str)(cnt);
    url = "https://toph.co/submissions/filter?author=590d7d60de14194eb555201c&start="+page_nb+"&verdict="
    cnt=cnt+64
    driver.get(url)
    quotes = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("syncer")
    if(len(quotes)==0):
        break
    for quote in quotes:
        row=quote.find_elements_by_tag_name("td")
        link=row[2].find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
        time1=row[3].find_elements_by_class_name('timestamp')
        time=time1[0].get_attribute('data-time')
        urlp=""
        if(link):
            urlp=link[0].get_attribute('href')
        sql1="SELECT * FROM submission WHERE id=%s AND oj='toph'"
        val1 = (row[0].text,)
        mycursor.execute(sql1,val1)
        myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
        if(len(myresult)==0):
            sql="INSERT INTO submission (id,dt,link,name,ver,oj) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,'toph')"
            val=(row[0].text,time,urlp,row[2].text,row[7].text)
            mycursor.execute(sql, val)
            mydb.commit()

print("successfull")
driver.close()
```

i am not expert in python so please help me to fix this problem :)

Comment: Don't post image of text. Post error message as plain text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is common "not in PATH" type of problem which is clearly indicated by the error message:

> Message: 'chromedriver3.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home

And the solution is to either use absolute path to the binary (if you can specify that) or to edit your global env `PATH` variable and add the location of that binary to it.

Comment: webdriver = 'C:/xampp/htdocs/Dairy/API/toph/python/chromedriver3.exe'
use this line instade of 
webdriver = 'chromedriver3.exe'

Answer (score 1):

I have faced a similar issue, it's looking to be this error is generic to windows, after setting shell=True in subprocess.py I able to resolve it.

Comment: Where exactly did you set shell=True to make this work?  It's been driving me crazy!!!